# flask route with default argument at beginning of path

Tags: flask

In flask, I can specify a default argument to a route thus:

```
@app.route("/user", defaults={'uid': 3})
@user.route('/user/<uid>')
def user(uid):
    # If /user or /user/ is requested, I'll see uid=3.
    # If /user/4 is requested, I'll see uid=4.
```

But I have a reverse path:

```
@app.route("/user", defaults={'thing': None})
@user.route('/<thing>/user/')
def user(thing):
    # If /user or /user/ is requested, I want to see thing == None.
    # If /dog/user/ is requested, I'll see thing == 'dog'.
```

Basically, if `thing` isn't provided, I'll do something a bit complex to compute it.  But it's fixed for a session, so I pass it around.

I know that this is asking quite a lot from the route parser.  (In particular, no `thing` had better conflict with another path, and I could easily cause quite a lot of inefficient backtracking if I'm not careful.  But `thing`s are designed never to conflict.)

The question is whether there's a way to do this?

What I've done is to create two functions.  But I have a handful of functions like this, so this is feeling heavy.

```
@app.route("/user")
def user():
    return redirect(url_for('main.user', thing=ComputeThing()))

@user.route('/<thing>/user/')
def user(thing):
    # If /user or /user/ is requested, I want to see thing == None.
    # If /dog/user/ is requested, I'll see thing == 'dog'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be missing something, can you expand on what you mean by a reverse path, because just using defaults seems to achieve what you want in your last example.

```
from flask import Flask
from random import choice

app = Flask(__name__)
choices = ['fox', 'cat', 'eel', 'cow']


def compute_thing():
    return choice(choices)


@app.route("/user", defaults={'thing': None})
@app.route("/<thing>/user/")
def user(thing):
    if thing is None:
        thing = compute_thing()

    return f"`thing` set as {thing}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc = app.test_client()

    ru = tc.get('/user')
    print(ru.data)  # `thing` set as cow'

    rd = tc.get('/dog/user/')
    print(rd.data)  # `thing` set as dog'
```

Comment: That does work.  I am not at all sure how I made it not work.  Sorry, and thanks.